# Finding unknowns in polynomial with two factors and remainder.

Tags: polynomials

$x^2-4x-12$ is a factor of $rx^3-sx^2+36$, find $r$ and $s$.

Long division gives $rx+(-s+4r)$ with remainder $12rx+4(-s+4r)x+36+12(-s+4r)$

Where I have difficulty with the logic  is that since $x^2-4x-12=0$ then the remainder is 0?
And from that we can say(how?) that $12r+4(-s+4r)=0$
And $36+12(-s+4r)=0$ also.
The rest is straightforward.

Comment: Sorry for powers eg X2 should read X squared etc.r=1, S=7.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It's cofactor is clearly $\,rx-3\,$ so multiply them and compare coef's of $x$ and $x^2\ \ $

Comment: Forgive me https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque but rx-3 is a cofactor of what?

Comment: $(ax+b)(x^2-4x-12) = rx^3 + \cdots + 36\,\Rightarrow\, a = r,\ b = -3\ \ $

Comment: Sorry https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242/bill-dubuque but the term S does not appear in either of your factors above??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Factor Theorem**
>   $x-a$ is a factor of $p(x)$ iff $p(a)=0$

Since $x^2-4x-12=(x-6)(x+2)$ is a factor of $p(x)=rx^3-sx^2+36$,
we know that $x-6$ and $x+2$ are factors of $p(x)$.
Thus $p(6)=0$ and $p(-2)=0$, that is $216r-36s+36=0$ and $-8r-4s+36=0$.
Solving the simultaneous linear equations give you $r=1,s=-7$.

To use long division, you need to divide $p(x)$ by $x-6$ and $x+2$.
By dividing $x-6$, you will get the remainder $216r-36s+36$.
By dividing $x+2$, you will get the remainder $-8r-4s+36$.
Since both are factors of $p(x)$, the remainder should be $0$.
Thus you get $216r-36s+36=0$ and $-8r-4s+36=0$.

If you straight away divide $p(x)$ by $x^2-4x-12$, the remainder you get is $12r+4(-s+4r)x+36+12(-s+4r)$.
Since the remainder must be zero polynomial,
you have $12r+4(-s+4r)=0$ and $36+12(-s+4r)=0$,
However, these two equations are multiple of one another so they cannot give you the solutions for $r$ and $s$.

Comment: Thanks https://math.stackexchange.com/users/165867/alan-wang for your much simpler and more direct solution. However that does not address my problems with the more painful long division method as presented by the author of the problem??

Comment: @saoceallaigh Updated. Inform me if you still have problem using long division.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/165867/alan-wang No All good now. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @saoceallaigh Welcome. And if you accept my answer, please press the tick on the left hand side of my answer. Thank you.